# Mutate no suma por filas

Tags: tidyverse

No consigo que con mutate() se me opere fila a fila y no a nivel del conjunto de la columna.
Concretamente, quiero extraer la variación de población de cada municipio (ubicados en las filas). Pero con la función de mutate, el resultado de"var_total" es el mismo para todos los municipios.

```
munpop_wide %>% 
  group_by(Codi, Nom) %>%
  summarise(
    var_total = ((1999-1998)/1998)*100)
```

Resultado:

Codi   Nom         var_total 
250019  Abella de la Conca  0.05005005
080018  Abrera              0.05005005
250024  Àger                0.05005005
250030  Agramunt            0.05005005
080023  Aguilar de Segarra  0.05005005
170010  Agullana            0.05005005
080142  Aiguafreda          0.05005005
430017  Aiguamúrcia         0.05005005

He probado también utilizando rowwise() pero tampoco cambia el resultado. ¿Qué podría hacer? Muchas gracias.

```
sub_wide <- munpop_wide %>% 
  select(Codi,
         Nom,
         pop.1998,
         pop.1999) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(var_total = ((1999-1998)/1998)*100)
```